# Ionic 3 badge not showing on iOS or Android

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have a mobile app built on Ionic 3, using Firebase and FCM plugin to send notifications.

I have 2 problems :

1. The badge never appears (tested on iOs and Android) (but the notifications are working normally)
2. When I click on the notification, I am re-directed to my application's home page. But I would like to be re-directed on a specific page of my application. Apparently, that should be specified by changing the "activity" on the "click_action" parameter, however my app doesn't have any activity.

Thanks for your help.

Here is my code :

```
  sendNotif(){
  this.postRequest()
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'key=xxxxx:xxxx')
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let postParams  = {
    "notification": {
      "title": "Mon-appli",
      "body": "Nouvelle réservation",
      "sound": "default",
      "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
      "icon": "fcm_push_icon"
    },
    "data": {
      "param1": "value1",
      "param2": "value2"
    },
    "to": "/topics/all",
    "priority": "high",
    "restricted_package_name": ""
  }

  this.http.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", postParams, options)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.nb_notif = this.nb_notif +1; 
    }, error => {});      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because I have the same problem with badge as you. But I think that I can answer your number 2 problem:

The redirection has nothing to do with your notification set-up. You'll need to unsubscribe  from the authentication observer. 
So unsubscribe in app.component.ts from the listener as follow:

```
const authUnsubscribe = afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => { 
if (user) {
       authUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
       this.rootPage = 'HomePage';
  }
else{
       this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
   } 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

And for question number 1:
You'll have to add badge:1 in your notification:{..} description.

```
  "notification": {
  "title": "Mon-appli",
  "body": "Nouvelle réservation",
  "sound": "default",
  "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
  "icon": "fcm_push_icon",
  "badge":1

}
```